# TransactionScope and deadlocks in sproc

Tags: sql-server-2005, c#-4.0, transactionscope

I've got a `sproc` that basically goes:

```
begin transaction
    SELECT
    UPDATE
    INSERT
commit transaction
```

This `sproc` is called inside a loop from two different threads in my application, both within a `TransactionScope` with default options.

Occasionally, my application deadlocks:

> "Transaction (Process ID 184) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction."

Is there anything I can do about this? Should I use a different isolation level?

Answer (score 3):

Default isolation level used by TransactionScope is Serializable which usually is unnecessary. Use a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.transactionscope.aspx) which takes [TransactionOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionoptions.aspx) to specify other level.

Example based on blog post from [David Baxter Browne](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2010/05/21/using-new-transactionscope-considered-harmful.aspx) (a great blog post describing this problem).

```
TransactionOptions tOptions= new TransactionOptions();
tOptions.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, tOptions))
{
  // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will this solve the deadlock? I'm having a hard time understanding where the deadlock comes from in my case.

Comment: @Johan: Using serializable can cause deadlock. See here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2010/05/21/using-new-transactionscope-considered-harmful.aspx